# Multiplying two byte numbers

Tags: java, byte

Somebody please explain me . Why below program produces **16** ?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    byte b1 = 60, b2 = 60;
    byte product = (byte) (b1 * b2);
    System.out.println(product);

}
```

Comment: What do you expect the result to be and why?

Comment: A byte can hold a number from 0-255 inclusive. What's 60*60? What's (60*60) mod 256 ?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I don't expect **3600** . I know this may overflow. But I don't know how this program prduces **16**.

Comment: Did you try the calculation @Blorgbeard suggested? (60*60) mod 256?

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan `int product = (byte) (b1 * b2) / 256;` ? I got **0**.

Comment: @Cataclysm mod 256, not divide 256. Modulus is normally `%` operator

Comment: @Sky THANKS! I got **16** too . I used `/` due to my eclipse suggestion ;D.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Integer overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow) issue.

60 * 60 = 3600 which is 111000010000 in binary form.

byte is a 8-bits data form. Therefore it will truncate into 8 bits of the data which is equivalent to 00010000 which is 16 in decimal. Hope this answer your question.

Answer (score 9):

This is because a `byte` can only store numbers ranging from `-128` to `127`, and `60 * 60 = 3,600`, which is way over the byte's maximum storage, so it creates an Integer Overflow error. To fix this, you could use:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    byte b1 = 60, b2 = 60;
    int product = b1 * b2;
    System.out.println(product);
}
```

A Byte can have 8 bits (binary digits), and 3600 is `111000010000` in binary form. (12 bits), so, the 4 extra bits in the beginning are dropped so it can fit in a byte, changing the binary to `00010000` instead of `111000010000`, and **00010000<sub>2</sub> = 16<sub>10</sub>**, so you get the output 16 instead of the desired 3600.

Answer (score 3):

Note the following program:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int b1 = 60, b2 = 60;
    int product = (byte) (b1 * b2);
    System.out.println(product);

}
```

If you noticed, it is the same as your, but instead of bytes, I am using ints. Yet, the result is the same. The issue is the `(byte)`, which gets only the last 8 bits of the number.

In fact you could even have used longs and you'd have the same value.

So the explanation is this:

The `(byte)` casting narrows it down, cutting the last 8 bits of the number, throwing away the  rest.

Since 60 * 60 is 111000010000, and the last 8 digits are 00010000, and since 00010000 is 16 in binary, that is what you get as the result.

To see numbers in their binary representation, you can use this:

```
    System.out.println(60 +" is "+Integer.toBinaryString(60) + " in binary");
    System.out.println((60*60) +" is "+Integer.toBinaryString(60*60) + " in binary");
    System.out.println("(byte)(60*60) is "+Integer.toBinaryString((byte)(60*60)) + " in binary");
```

Which outputs this:

```
60 is 111100 in binary
3600 is 111000010000 in binary
(byte)(60*60) is 10000 in binary
```